# TYPO3 Powermail: Different recipients depending on formfield?

Tags: typo3, powermail

I have a question (TYPO3 7.6 / Powermail 3.19): Is it possible, to send a form to different recipients depending on the content of a formfield?

To be more exact: I have a mandatory formfield, where a serial number should be filled in. If this number begins with a 3, the form should be send to recipient-1 and if it begins with an 8, recipient-2 should be informed.

Any idea how to make this?

Many thanx :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use predefined receivers function in powermail - see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/DynamicReceiver/Index.html
A userFunc could handle the serial number logic.